# Firebase optimize multiple request with same data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple react app with firebase, i have my user logged in

I have a button, when is pressed i need to get the current user score in firebase ( first request) and increment this value with a random number (second request)

Get user

```
firebase.database().ref('user' + uid).child().once()
```

Update user :

```
firebase.database().ref('user' + uid).update({score : newValue})
```

Each time user press the button i made this two firebase request to get the current score and increment it

In most case user can click 150 to 600 times on the button whose can cause slowness

Do you have any suggestion to optimize my app and avoid of calling 1200 ( 2 request by 600 click) times firebase ?

Comment: If this is a 'random number' on the second request, why do all this work in a database - just use javascript......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why can't you try "transaction" query on the firebase.The update function takes the current state of the data as an argument and returns the new desired state you would like to write. what you have to do is just pass the key to the transaction like below

```
 firebase.database().ref('user' + uid).child('score')
      .transaction(function(current){ // current will hold current value of the key             
           return current + newValue ; // this return will automatically updates the new value to the firebase
       });
```

Transaction is really good for these scenarios [Follow up this link for more deets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write?authuser=0#save_data_as_transactions)
So if you use transaction then you can reduce two queries into one.

I Hope this helps.

Comment: Please consider up voting the answer